# net 5 confusion on refencing nuget packages using .net framework

Tags: visual-studio, .net-5, csproj

I have a project that is using *net5.0* as **TargetFramework** (tried *net6.0* preview as well) that is referencing 2 nuget packages.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU</Platforms>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Com.aaa" Version="xxxx" />
    <PackageReference Include="Com.bbb" Version="xxxx" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

[image]

The first nuget has *net48* as **TargetFramework** while the second one targets *netstandard2.0*.
As I was expecting, the second one is imported just fine but not the first one.

It does not show any error nor warning but I'm unable to use anything that is defined in it within the code. There's obviously a compatibility issue but I'm not understanding what it is.

Is it related to the *Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web"* in the csproj?

Comment: .NET 5 is .NET *Core* 5. You *can't* use a .NET Framework package or library in a .NET Core application. You'll have to find a version that targets .NET Core or .NET Standard

Comment: That explains it thanks. Is it going to be the same with .NET 6?

Comment: That will be the case in .NET going forward, if packages aren‘t updated, there is a risk to using them. You can set `<AssetTargetFallback>$(AssetTargetFallback);net48</AssetTargetFallback>` inside of a `<PropertyGroup>` in your csproj file to force resolve the .NET Framework assets but that comes with the risk of not working at runtime